# Regex required: It should match for following patterns

Tags: java, regex

Valid:

1. `((int)10)`
2. `(int)10`
3. `((char)((x+y)&1))`
4. `((int *)1)`

Invalid:

1. `(a-b)`
2. `(a&=b)`
3. `a`
4. `((a))`

Comment: Is this valid: `((char)((((x+y)` ?

Answer (score 8):

The language of (balanced) parenthesized expressions is **not regular**, i.e., you can't write a regular expressions matching these kind of strings.

See [SO question: *Why are regular expressions called "regular" expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975465/why-are-regular-expressions-called-regular-expressions) and [Wikipedia: Regular Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

You need to work with a more capable parsing technique such as a CFG with for instance [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

You could start with something like:

```
CastedExpression ::= Cast Expression | LPAR CastedExpression RPAR
Cast             ::= LPAR Type RPAR
Expression       ::= Sum | Product | Litteral | LPAR Expression RPAR | ...
Type             ::= char | int | Type ASTERISK | ...
```

(*Feel free to edit grammar above if you find any obvious improvements).*

Comment: Conditional +1 if you can supply that grammar.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

> The language of (balanced)
>   parenthesized expressions is not
>   regular, i.e., you can't write a
>   regular expressions matching these
>   kind of strings.

is true only of classic regular expressions in the pathologically formal sense. It does *not* apply to the practical patterns which many of us use daily.

For example, using the third string from the original list of valid inputs, this Perl code:

```
my $str = "((char)((x+y)&1))";
my $w   = length length $str ;
my $rx  = qr{ (?<PAREN>
                \(
                   (?:
                       [^()] +
                     |
                       (?&PAREN)
                   ) *
                \)
              )
          }x;

while ($str =~ /(?=$rx)/g) {
    printf "Matched from %*d to %*d: %s%s\n" =>
        $w => pos($str),
        $w => pos($str) + length($+{PAREN})-1,
        " " x pos($str)   =>     $+{PAREN};
}
```

quite handily produces the following output:

```
Matched from  0 to 16: ((char)((x+y)&1))
Matched from  1 to  6:  (char)
Matched from  7 to 15:        ((x+y)&1)
Matched from  8 to 12:         (x+y)
```

I can't tell from eyeballing the original set of inputs  just what it is that makes one valid and the other invalid. Still, I'm sure some elaboration of the code I gave above will work perfectly fine.

However, you *will* have to write it in Perl, as Java's patterns just aren't powerful enough. ☹

Answer (score 0):

Adding to aioobe's answer:

Looks like you're trying to write an expression parser. As already said in the other answer it is not possible using a regex. You should consider using an expression parser such as JEP or write one yourself using javacc.