# Regex required: To return substring which is present after first completion of parentheses

Tags: java, regex

Example-
1)(abc)xxx  -->            output-xxx

2)(abc)(xxx) -->           output-xxx

3)((abc)xxx) --->          output-xxx

4)((abc) xxx + yyy)-->     output-xxx+yyy

5)((abc)) --->             output-null

Comment: You can't count balanced parentheses with a regexp. You'll need to use something else.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, but it has the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903965/regex-required-it-should-match-for-following-patterns

Comment: True. http://www.texttoolkit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63:parsing-balanced-parenthesis-with-regular-expressions&catid=35:technology&Itemid=55

Answer (score 0):

This actually does what you ask for for all your examples, but I suspect is not what you wanted

```
[^\)]+\)[\(]*([^\)]*)
```

([tested here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html))