# Are regular expressions (regex) really regular?

Tags: regex, grammar, regular-language, backreference, finite-state-automaton

I understand how regular expressions got their name, and have read the related question ([Why are regular expressions called "regular" expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975465/why-are-regular-expressions-called-regular-expressions)), but am still wondering whether regular expressions are always regular.

For example, how can back-references be regular? Would that not require some memory and thus be impossible to match/generate by a finite state automaton?

Comment: The link in the answer to the question you reference states (in wikipedia), *as opposed to many regular expressions engines provided by modern programming languages, which are augmented with features that allow recognition of languages that cannot be expressed by a classic regular expression*. I interpret that as the evolution of regex moved it away from it's original idea of expressing *regular languages*.

Comment: @ClasG: Thank you. It also provides the link for a paragraph that exactly answers my question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link in the answer to the question you reference states (in wikipedia), *as opposed to many regular expressions engines provided by modern programming languages, which are augmented with features that allow recognition of languages that cannot be expressed by a classic regular expression*.

So I would say that the evolution of regex moved it away from it's original idea of expressing regular languages.

From the [Wikipedia article on regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages):

> Many features found in virtually all modern regular expression
>   libraries provide an expressive power that far exceeds the regular
>   languages. For example, many implementations allow grouping
>   subexpressions with parentheses and recalling the value they match in
>   the same expression (backreferences). This means that, among other
>   things, a pattern can match strings of repeated words like "papa" or
>   "WikiWiki", called squares in formal language theory. The pattern for
>   these strings is `(.+)\1`.

Answer (score 3):

Modern extensions including back-references make the regex systems not a candidate of regular languages, however IMO they can be lifted to context-free languages but not to Turing machines.

Regular grammars share a common property called pumping lemma. You can check the example [here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/g51mal/notes-3x.pdf) which proves 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> is not a regular grammar (that is quite similar to back-references). Here is how it can be shown that back-references don't satisfy pumping lemma property.

- Pumping lemma in current context: to show that a regex system is regular grammar, there needs to be a finite length p such that all strings that match the regex and have length equals to or greater than p can be split up in three substrings xyz such that y is not an empty string and all the strings represented by xy<sup>*</sup>z (y pumped for [0, infinite) times) match with the regex.
- If we can show no such p can satisfy the conditions for the regex then it is not in regular grammar.
- For back-references we will need to have two of these pumping strings that too of equal length, one for the sub-pattern in captured group and one in the backreference. This is exactly what the push-down automata or context free languages are. There is also a pumping lemma for context free grammars that is based on splitting into uvwxy where v and x can be pumped equally n times. We can show that the regex with back-references system satisfies this lemma.

Comment: "however IMO they can be lifted to context-free languages but not to Turing machines" << this is false. 1) you are confusing formal languages with abstract machines. 2) every context free languages are recursive and/or recursively enumerable, so there is a Turing machine that recognizes it. 3) backreferences are not even context-free: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would like to defend some of the points as a constructive exercise. Each point separately. 1) The context-free languages and push down automata abstract machine are exactly the same in terms of power, similarly are the regular grammars and finite automata. I don't see a problem in using them interchangeably. 2) True, but context-free grammars are not turing complete, this is what I meant. 3) I still think a single back reference might be addressed by pumping lemma for CFG however I understand that claim needs some backing. I should add the link that you provided. :)